# Send jQuery parameters to server side and create output text file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using this script:
https://jsfiddle.net/b7wjj39p/1/

I am trying to save the data that is coming after "the winner is:" (after pressing on "spin") to a text file on the server.

I have tried to use this way of saving it:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("myfile.txt", "w");
$txt = "my name\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "my name\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

but I was unable to figure out no how to send the parameters to the server side, and from there to the text file.

Answer (score 0):

First let us see how to get the value. It seems the value is stored in the variable "text". So after the wheel has stopped, the StopRotateWheel function runs. I added an 'alert(text)` after the wheel stops and as you can see the variable is isolated.

```
    function stopRotateWheel () {
            clearTimeout(spinTimeout);
            var degrees = startAngle * 180 / Math.PI + 90;
            var arcd = arc * 180 / Math.PI;
            var index = Math.floor((360 - degrees % 360) / arcd);
            ctx.save();
            ctx.font = params.resultTextFont;
            var text = pplArray[index];
            $(params.winnerDiv).html(text).show();
            alert(text);
            ctx.fillText(text, 250 - ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 250 + 10); // this is showing the text
            ctx.restore();
        }
```

Instead of alerting it, you can add it to a hidden input field. Let us call that field "winner" :

```
 $("#winner").val(text)
```

Then you can send this value to PHP using a simple POST using ajax/jquery like this:

```
function sendwinnertophp(){
    var winner = $("#winner").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getwinner.php",
            data: {winner:winner},
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
        })
        .success(function(response) {   
            alert("winner sent to php!");
        }); 
}
```

Comment: i have added the code you wrote to the file and created a new file named "getwinner.php" but i still don't get the alert "winner sent to php!". please see here: http://zeevm.co.il/rollet/

Comment: That was an example of how you can do it. You are not getting the alert because you are not sending back a success message from PHP.

Comment: thank you ! i think the data is not being sent. i created the php file and wrote some echo code but it dosn't print nothing: $winner = $_POST['winner'];
if($winner != "")
{
    echo $winner;
}

Comment: post the code you have written so far and we can see what the issue is ;)